# Salesforce request google project protected by iap

Tags: google-app-engine, salesforce, apex-code, google-cloud-iam, salesforce-communities

I write this post for help with a development we want to put into production on our salesforce environment.

Indeed, we are experiencing difficulties when we try to connect a google api developed with appEngine and protected by IAP.

During the different tests from the documentation we found on the internet, we did :

- Configurations in the Auth. Providers of salesforce mentioning the consumer Key and the secret we generated from our google API.
- The creation of Named Credentials in order to use our auth.provider with different protocols (OAuth 2.0, openID)

During the different tests via the apex console in order to access our google application endpoint, when calling the different "named credential" we encounter errors during the token exchange flow between salesforce and the google application. "Invalid IAP credentials: Unable to parse JWT".

Apex code to call the :

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:"my named credential"');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Could you please tell us where the problem can come from and possibly the best practices to interconnect Salesforce and a personal project developed on appEngine google and protected by IAP while managing the tokens?

Thanks in advance for your help.

We are trying to create an authentication via a Google OAuth 2.0 client ID from Salesforce.